# Angularjs: Radio button in bootstrap is not sending false value

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

Hi guys i just want to ask how to solve this issue.
i have a radio button

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="radio-inline">
       <input type="radio" name="radioOpt" ng-model="modalData.mine" ng-value="true" ng-change="eval()">mine</label>
                                        </div>
</div>

/* my input fields that is set to disabled *

<div class="col-sm-2"  style="padding:0;margin:0;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input ng-disabled="disabled " class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="modalData.input">
    </div>
</div>
```

controller :

```
$scope.eval= function() {
    if($scope.modalData.mine) {
        $scope.disabled = false;
    } else {
        $scope.disabled = true;
    }       
}
```

heres the codepen guys : http://codepen.io/pango143/pen/YNNJwK

the scenario is i have a disabled input which only be enabled when the mine radio btn is selected. i dont have problem with that, But the problem is when i click another radio btn the input is not returning to disabled state which means the radio button is not sending false value in the binding.

Comment: Add plnkr or fiddile.

Comment: Do you have another `name="radioOpt"` with `ng-value="false"`?

Comment: I think that your issue is because you're using ng-value, remove this attribute and see what happens. Because the default values of radio/checkbox is a boolean, you use ng-value to explicitly define another value (string) when selected.

Comment: Need to see full HTML and JS, example provided is'nt showing enough.

Comment: @TomJohnson, Its value still be boolean

Comment: i add some codepen guys thank for the response